# Cross Browser Event object normalization?

Tags: javascript, events, cross-browser, dom-events

I'm looking for a good resource on event normalization on the event object. I'm trying to do it myself but I keep feeling like I'm going to miss something.

Here's what I have so far, tell me if I missed anything.

```
var eFix = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    e.offsetX = e.offsetX || e.layerX;
    e.offsetY = e.offsetY || e.layerY;
    e.relatedTarget = e.relatedTarget ||
        e.type == 'mouseover' ? e.fromElement : e.toElement;
    e.target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.nodeType === 3) target = target.parentNode; //Safari bug
    return e;
};
```

Has anyone seen a complete normalization function? Did I miss anything?
(Needless to say we're going for W3C model not IE)

Comment: Are you against using jQuery? That would take care of this for you...

Comment: @Brad Christie It's for learning purposes and I'd rather not bloat up my code just for event normalization

Comment: @qwertymk I agree. People are too quick to include every library known to man simply to use a single feature from it. It's sad really.

Comment: I like how no-one has actually said `yes this is correct!`

Answer (score 2):

There is another problem with your code:

`e.layerX` only works on *positioned* elements, so at the very least you need to add a "position:relative" to your element to function. Secondly `e.offsetX` only works correctly in *IE8 and later*, so you should probably refrain from using it either way (although I am using them right now, but this only needs to work in specific browsers).