# Fix Native JavaScript Events

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I'm wondering if there is any well established way to fix browser inconsistencies with DOM events. What is the best way to **fix** events?

Below is what I am playing with right now (though still broken).

```
Event.prototype.fix = function()
{
    //if ( ! event) var event = window.event;

    // Fix target property, if necessary (IE 6/7/8 & Safari2)
    if ( ! this.target)
    {
        this.target = this.srcElement || document;
    }

    // Target should not be a text node (Safari)
    if (this.target.nodeType === 3)
    {
        this.target = event.target.parentNode;
    }

    // Add which for key events
    if (this.which == null)
    {
        this.which = this.charCode != null ? this.charCode : this.keyCode;
    }

    // For mouse/key events; add metaKey if it's not there (#3368, IE6/7/8)
    if (this.metaKey === undefined)
    {
        this.metaKey = this.ctrlKey;
    }

    this.posx = 0;
    this.posy = 0;

    if (this.pageX || this.pageY)
    {
        this.posx = this.pageX;
        this.posy = this.pageY;
    }
    else if (this.clientX || this.clientY)
    {
        this.posx = this.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
            + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        this.posy = this.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
            + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
};
```

Comment: Also found a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643249/cross-browser-event-object-normalization) with a similar function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Slayer of browser inconsistencies since 2006.

***Edit***

If you are concerned about the 32kb, then use [Google's CDN](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery). Lots of sites use it, so there is a good chance that the file will be cached on a majority of your users' computers.

Comment: haha, that is one way. But I don't like adding 30kB+ just to fix a simple DOM event.

Comment: Fair enough, but it's a popular option

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're already pulling code out of jQuery. (Exact line matches from event.js)  This seems like the best approach you could take.

Look at [mouseHooks](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L487) and [keyHooks](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L474) for their cross browser fixes for those event types.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are talking about the event object, not events in general.

In javascript, a native object is one provided by the ECMAScript implementation or created by ECMAScript code (e.g. `function fred(){}`, `var obj = {}`). Everything else is provided by the host environment and is therefore a host object (e.g. window, DOM elements).

Therefore the event object is a host object, not a "native javascript" object.

A reasonable approach in most programming environments is to only worry about the things that directly affect the program being developed. That strategy leads to only "fixing" event objects where their inconsistencies affect specific parts of code. It doesn't seem sensible to worry about properties that are not used, whose inconsistencies don't affect the program being written, or that are not applicable to the particular event (e.g. what is the value of pageX for a load event, and why should it be set to 0 rather then left as *undefined*).

The kind of programming where every possible inconsistency is written into a single function leads to [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), where the reason for doing particular things (if ever there was a good reason for doing them at all) is lost and they are perpetuated simply because they exist in some "best practice" version of "cross browser" code.

For example, does anyone remember which versions of Safari set the *target* property to text nodes if they were the event target? If not, and no such browser exists in use, why is it still in such code?

If it is included because some future browser may also make text nodes event targets, and for some reason it is decided that event targets must always be elements (or at least, nodes that implement the element interface), then wouldn't it be more sensible to do:

```
if (this.target.nodeType != 1 && this.target.parentNode) {
  this.target = this.target.parentNode;
}
```

as a more general fix for the possibility that an event target isn't an element?

Under what circumstances would `event.srcElement == false`, and why should it be set to the document node rather than say the *body* or *head* element?